# iPad required launch images

Tags: ios, ipad, landscape, launch, landscape-portrait

I'm developing a universal iOS app that only supports portrait and upside-down interface orientations. When supplying the launch images in Xcode, I see that I have warnings for landscape orientations, even having only portrait and upside down enabled in device orientations settings. Does this mean that I need to supply landscape launch images anyway? I don't find this clear in Apple's documentation.

Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem and I think it does not really matter. Though you can verify if this will affect your app by "Archiving" and "Validating" the "Archive" on Xcode. It's like a step before submitting the app for review at Apple.

Comment: an iPad app includes at least one launch image in portrait
orientation and at least one launch image in landscape orientation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. These are warnings. Apple would prefer you support all orientations on iPad, and recommend you do, but they do not require it. (Yet)

Answer (score 0):

Launch Images in Landscape Orientation is optional and xCode ignores it if it is not provided in Application.

However, If you are using Xcode5 there will be a folder named **Images.xcassets** > Launch Images > There will be a blank icon available for iPad Landscape  > Right Click on those 1x and 2x icon > Remove Selected Items.

This will remove the warnings that you are having in your case.

Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

an iPad app includes at least one launch image in portrait
orientation and at least one launch image in landscape orientation.